# Google Places API - Add Places

Tags: html, google-maps

I am trying to write this in HMTL https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions#PlaceReportRequests but I have really big difficulties. Can you help me, what is the HTML code for creating a new places ? I have got API key but I don't know how to  put things together.

Comment: have a look for REST and jQuery

Comment: R u using google maps v2 or v3???

Answer (score 1):

See this eg. You can get an idea.

Google Maps API Sample

```
function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
    GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function() {
      alert("You clicked the map.");
     });
  }
}

</script>
```

​You can get more examples in this link.
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground